# Problem using findOne in Node JS to find a document with a Number in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a simple app and in this case using express and EJS, I'm just accessing some data in my database. My database is MongoDB and I'm accessing it with mongoose.
All goes well when I use a find and findOne like those:

```
router.post('/ConsProducto', async (req, res) => {
    const productos= await Productos.find();
    console.log(productos);
```

That gives

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61982502b4d3d91817558358"),
    codigo_producto: 1,
    nombre_producto: 'Melocotones',
    nitproveedor: 1,
    precio_compra: '25505',
    ivacompra: 215,
    precio_venta: 30351
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61982502b4d3d91817558359"),
    codigo_producto: 2,
    nombre_producto: 'Manzanas',
    nitproveedor: 3,
    precio_compra: '18108',
    ivacompra: 19,
    precio_venta: 21549
  }
```

All the way until 19, those are the elements that I posted on that database. With findOne

```
router.post('/ConsProducto', async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Productos.findOne({ nombre_producto: "Queso"});
    console.log(products);
```

That gives

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61982502b4d3d91817558362"),
  codigo_producto: 11,
  nombre_producto: 'Queso',
  nitproveedor: 5,
  precio_compra: '26571',
  ivacompra: 19,
  precio_venta: 31619
}
```

All great, but when I try to use a number, I get null. I have tried using casts to convert it, like Number() or NumberInt(), using parseInt(),  because in the database appears to be an Int32, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

```
router.post('/ConsProducto', async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Productos.findOne({ codigo_producto: NumberInt(2)});
    console.log(products);
```

That gives me

```
null
```

Also when created without cast

```
router.post('/ConsProducto', async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Productos.findOne({ codigo_producto: '2'});
    console.log(products);
```

That gives me

```
null
```

Adding the module of "Productos" just in case somebody needs it

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema =mongoose.Schema;

const ProductosSchema = new Schema({
    codigo_producto: Number,
    nombre_producto: String,
    nitproveedor:Number,
    precio_compra:String,
    ivacompra:Number,
    precio_venta: Number    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('db_productos',ProductosSchema);
```

Adding the way of insertion

```
 csvtojson().fromFile("./public/upload/productos.csv").then(source => {
                    var results = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
                        var linea = {
                            codigo_producto: source[i]["codigo_producto"],
                            nombre_producto: source[i]["nombre_producto"],
                            nitproveedor: source[i]["nitproveedor"],
                            precio_compra: source[i]["precio_compra"],
                            ivacompra: source[i]["ivacompra"],
                            precio_venta: source[i]["precio_venta"]
                        
                        };
                        results.push(linea);
                    }
                    console.log(results);
                    var collectionName = "db_productos";
                    var collection = mongoose.connection.db.collection(collectionName);
                    collection.insertMany(results, {ordered:false} ,(err, result) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        if (result) {
                            console.log("Successfull");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: We need to see the insert statements for those fields. You should just be able to pass the number directly as an integer without any conversion.

Comment: You can insert number directly, no need to convert it

Comment: @juan try:

    const products = await Productos.findOne({ codigo_producto: '2'});

(Mongoose will cast  the string value to a number)

Comment: Yes, I tried inserting it flat as a number. It gives me null as well. That's the reason why I started to try casting that string. 
I don't find any logical reason why it works when I look for a variable that is defined as a string, and not when I try it with a number.

Comment: `const products = await Productos.findOne( { codigo_producto: 2 } )` - this should work (based upon what you had posted in your question), You can verify if the query filter works in a tool like `mongo` shell (or `mongosh`).

Comment: To check the types, try running `Productos.find({},{ codigo_producto_type: { $type: "$codigo_producto"}})`